# How to detect the given text is same in two different language using apache Tika Language detection tool

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class LanguageDetection {
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException
{
LanguageIdentifier identifier = new LanguageIdentifier("option");
String language = identifier.getLanguage();
System.out.println("Language of the given content is : " + language);
}
}

Output : Language of the given content is : fr
```

Here, it displays FR but its same in EN also but its not display EN.  I want to check the text "option" is English or not. So Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue please?

Comment: Try and use the newer **LanguageDetector** class.

Comment: Tried LanguageDetector class but its also same. Do you have any idea about List<LanguageResult> detectAll(String text)
Utility wrapper that detects the language of a given chunk of text.